# Unexpected end of JSON input in reactJS

Tags: json, reactjs

I have the below json from the API

```
{"error":false,"session_id":"vb8pf4n7255deq4oj3tn2k1nlr","data":{"items":[{"type":"Obituary","object":{"obituaryId":"40811","deathDay":"2019-09-22","funeral":{"funeralDate":"2019-09-23","funeralTime":"16:00 ","place":"\u0643\u0646\u064a\u0633\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u064a\u062f\u0629\u060c \u0628\u0633\u0648\u0633\u060c \u0639\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0647","lat":"33.841211","long":"35.530477","communityId":"604"},"name":"\u0627\u0644\u0635\u064a\u062f\u0644\u064a \u0639\u0627\u0626\u062f\u0629 \u064a\u0648\u0633\u0641 \u063a\u0646\u0637\u0648\u0633 \u0635\u0627\u062f\u0631","photo":"http:\/\/khoolood.kh\/\/css\/images\/defaults\/obituary.png","categoryId":"8"}},{"type":"Obituary","object":{"obituaryId":"40810","deathDay":"2019-09-22","funeral":{"funeralDate":"2019-09-23","funeralTime":"16:00 ","place":"\u00c9glise Notre-Dame, \u00e0 Bsous, Aley","lat":"33.841211","long":"35.530477","communityId":"604"},"name":"A\u00efda Youssef Ghantous Sader","photo":"http:\/\/khoolood.kh\/\/css\/images\/defaults\/obituary.png","categoryId":"8"}},{"type":"Obituary","object":{"obituaryId":"40809","deathDay":"2019-09-20","funeral":{"funeralDate":"2019-09-22","funeralTime":"15:00 ","place":"\u0643\u0627\u062a\u062f\u0631\u0627\u0626\u064a\u0629 \u0633\u064a\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0634\u0627\u0631\u0629 \u0644\u0644\u0633\u0631\u064a\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0643\u0627\u062b\u0648\u0644\u064a\u0643\u060c \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062a\u062d\u0641","lat":"33.877744","long":"35.516491","communityId":"647"},"name":"\u0623\u0646\u0637\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u062a\u0648\u0641\u064a\u0642 \u0639\u0628\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0648\u0627\u062d\u062f","photo":"http:\/\/khoolood.kh\/\/css\/images\/defaults\/obituary.png","categoryId":"8"}},{"type":"Obituary","object":{"obituaryId":"40807","deathDay":"2019-09-20","funeral":{"funeralDate":"2019-09-21","funeralTime":"16:00 ","place":"\u0643\u0646\u064a\u0633\u0629 \u0645\u0627\u0631 \u0625\u0644\u064a\u0627\u0633\u060c \u0627\u0644\u0644\u064a\u0644\u0643\u064a\u060c \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u064a\u062c\u0629\u060c \u0628\u0639\u0628\u062f\u0627","lat":"33.833957","long":"35.513066","communityId":"1307"},"name":"\u062c\u0627\u0646 \u0637\u0627\u0646\u064a\u0648\u0633 \u0639\u0637\u0627\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647","photo":"http:\/\/khoolood.kh\/\/css\/images\/defaults\/obituary.png","categoryId":"8"}},{"type":"Commemoration","object":{"obituaryId":"40796","deathDay":"2018-09-24","funeral":{"funeralDate":"2019-09-24","funeralTime":"12:00","place":"\u063a\u064a\u0631 \u0645\u062a\u0648\u0641\u0631","lat":"","long":"","communityId":""},"name":"\u0627\u0644\u062f\u0643\u062a\u0648\u0631 \u0623\u0646\u0637\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u062c\u0648\u0632\u0641 \u062e\u0628\u0651\u0627\u0632","photo":"http:\/\/khoolood.kh\/\/css\/images\/defaults\/obituary.png","categoryId":"6"}},{"type":"Commemoration","object":{"obituaryId":"40795","deathDay":"2018-09-24","funeral":{"funeralDate":"2019-09-24","funeralTime":"12:00","place":"\u063a\u064a\u0631 \u0645\u062a\u0648\u0641\u0631","lat":"","long":"","communityId":""},"name":"\u062c\u0627\u0646 \u0643\u0644\u0648\u062f \u0645\u0631\u0633\u0627\u0644 \u062d\u0631\u0641\u0648\u0634","photo":"http:\/\/khoolood.kh\/\/css\/images\/defaults\/obituary.png","categoryId":"6"}},{"type":"Commemoration","object":{"obituaryId":"40794","deathDay":"2018-09-24","funeral":{"funeralDate":"2019-09-24","funeralTime":"12:00","place":"\u063a\u064a\u0631 \u0645\u062a\u0648\u0641\u0631","lat":"","long":"","communityId":""},"name":"\u062f\u0648\u0631\u0627 \u0644\u0648\u064a\u0633 \u0635\u0627\u0644\u062d","photo":"http:\/\/khoolood.kh\/\/css\/images\/defaults\/obituary.png","categoryId":"6"}},{"type":"Commemoration","object":{"obituaryId":"40793","deathDay":"2018-09-24","funeral":{"funeralDate":"2019-09-24","funeralTime":"12:00","place":"\u063a\u064a\u0631 \u0645\u062a\u0648\u0641\u0631","lat":"","long":"","communityId":""},"name":"\u0631\u064a\u0645\u0648\u0646 \u0625\u0644\u064a\u0627\u0633 \u0645\u0635\u0631\u064a","photo":"http:\/\/khoolood.kh\/\/css\/images\/defaults\/obituary.png","categoryId":"6"}},{"type":"Commemoration","object":{"obituaryId":"40792","deathDay":"2018-09-24","funeral":{"funeralDate":"2019-09-24","funeralTime":"12:00","place":"\u063a\u064a\u0631 \u0645\u062a\u0648\u0641\u0631","lat":"","long":"","communityId":""},"name":"\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0630 \u0623\u0646\u064a\u0633 \u0645\u062d\u0645\u0648\u062f \u0623\u0628\u0648 \u0631\u0627\u0641\u0639","photo":"http:\/\/khoolood.kh\/\/css\/images\/defaults\/obituary.png","categoryId":"6"}},{"type":"Commemoration","object":{"obituaryId":"40791","deathDay":"2018-09-24","funeral":{"funeralDate":"2019-09-24","funeralTime":"12:00","place":"\u063a\u064a\u0631 \u0645\u062a\u0648\u0641\u0631","lat":"","long":"","communityId":""},"name":"\u064a\u0648\u0633\u0641 \u0625\u0644\u064a\u0627\u0633 \u0627\u0644\u062d\u0648\u064a\u0643","photo":"http:\/\/khoolood.kh\/\/css\/images\/defaults\/obituary.png","categoryId":"6"}},{"type":"Commemoration","object":{"obituaryId":"40790","deathDay":"2018-09-24","funeral":{"funeralDate":"2019-09-24","funeralTime":"12:00","place":"\u063a\u064a\u0631 \u0645\u062a\u0648\u0641\u0631","lat":"","long":"","communityId":""},"name":"\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0630 \u062c\u0648\u0631\u062c \u064a\u0648\u0633\u0641 \u0636\u0648\u0651","photo":"http:\/\/khoolood.kh\/\/css\/images\/defaults\/obituary.png","categoryId":"6"}},{"type":"Obituary","object":{"obituaryId":"40789","deathDay":"2019-09-14","funeral":{"funeralDate":"2019-09-17","funeralTime":"17:00","place":"\u0643\u0627\u062a\u062f\u0631\u0627\u0626\u064a\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0642\u062f\u064a\u0633 \u0646\u064a\u0642\u0648\u0644\u0627\u0648\u0633 \u0644\u0644\u0631\u0648\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0631\u062b\u0648\u0630\u0643\u0633 (\u0645\u0627\u0631 \u0646\u0642\u0648\u0644\u0627)\u060c \u0632\u062d\u0644\u0629","lat":"33.847231","long":"35.903866","communityId":"706"},"name":"\u0627\u0644\u0645\u062a\u0631\u0648\u0628\u0648\u0644\u064a\u062a \u0625\u0633\u0628\u064a\u0631\u064a\u062f\u0648\u0646 \u062e\u0648\u0631\u064a","photo":"http:\/\/khoolood.kh\/storage\/obituary\/13662608021333066283.jpg","categoryId":"8"}},{"type":"Commemoration","object":{"obituaryId":"40788","deathDay":"2002-09-23","funeral":{"funeralDate":"2019-09-23","funeralTime":"12:00","place":"Non Fourni","lat":"","long":"","communityId":""},"name":"Abdel Majid Youssef Bey El-Zein","photo":"http:\/\/khoolood.kh\/\/css\/images\/defaults\/obituary.png","categoryId":"6"}},{"type":"Commemoration","object":{"obituaryId":"40787","deathDay":"2002-09-23","funeral":{"funeralDate":"2019-09-23","funeralTime":"12:00","place":"\u063a\u064a\u0631 \u0645\u062a\u0648\u0641\u0631","lat":"","long":"","communityId":""},"name":"\u0639\u0628\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062c\u064a\u062f \u064a\u0648\u0633\u0641 \u0628\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u0632\u064a\u0646","photo":"http:\/\/khoolood.kh\/\/css\/images\/defaults\/obituary.png","categoryId":"6"}},{"type":"Commemoration","object":{"obituaryId":"40775","deathDay":"2018-09-23","funeral":{"funeralDate":"2019-09-23","funeralTime":"12:00","place":"\u063a\u064a\u0631 \u0645\u062a\u0648\u0641\u0631","lat":"","long":"","communityId":""},"name":"\u0623\u0646\u062c\u0644\u064a\u0646\u0627 \u064a\u0648\u0633\u0641 \u0645\u0627\u0631\u0648\u0646","photo":"http:\/\/khoolood.kh\/\/css\/images\/defaults\/obituary.png","categoryId":"6"}}]}}
```

It is valid when i run it on jsonlint.com, however when i pass it in react i get an error "Unexpected end of JSON input". this is the code in react:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({loading: true})
    fetch('http://domainname.kh/en-lb/v2/api?action=recentObituaries')
        .then(data => data.json()) //error on this line
        .then(data => this.setState({data, loading: false}))
}
```

The error is fixed if I edit the API, to return like this:

```
echo "[" . json_encode($response) . "]";
```

instead of this:

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

thanks for the help, I just started learning react.

Answer (score 0):

i put working example but cannot to get fetch from the address in your code:
Also try to replace  data.json() to data.text() and make JSON.parse
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-mpdhn